# Working with ES6 linting using Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm learning about ES6 syntax and I'm using Visual Studio Code.

I'm using the `let` declaration syntax (for example), and it is being highlighted as an error.

I am getting this message:

> `"[jshint] 'let' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz). (W104)".`

So I'm wondering:

1. How should to configure my editor so that I don't get these errors?
2. Or rather, how do I enable ES6 linting for my project?

I have tried using `eslintrc` (though I'm not familiar with it) and I've also tried using the ESLint extension, however I still get the same error.

Thanks.

Comment: you should just uninstall eslint or jshint plugins..

Comment: Thanks @MudOnTire, i thought i needed to do the opposite.So when would i need to use eslint or jshint?

Comment: This [link](http://donovanbrown.com/post/Enabling-jshint-es6-support-in-VS-Code) might help you to enabling jshint es6 support in VS Code.

Comment: @RobC thanks i installed jshint again and followed the instructions on that link. I'm not getting errors now.

Comment: Thanks for the revision to the question @RobC

Comment: You're welcome @JSpecs. It's sounds like you've resolved the issue now. I suggest that you provide your own answer in the section below (see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)). You can explain the steps you took to get it working as It will probably be beneficial to future readers. You can then accept your own answer after 48 hours.

Comment: Thanks didn't know i could do that.

Answer (score 4):

I solved my problem by pasting the following code in my `settings.json` file in the workspace settings found in `File > Preferences > Settings`:

```
 "settings": {"jshint.options": {"esversion": 6},
```